# Which package I should select for FxCop when installing Windows SDK 7.1?

Tags: fxcop

I have installed VS2010 Professional on my machine and now I need to install the latest FxCop.
However, I don't know which package listed in the win7.1 sdk should be selected. I really don't want to install the files that are not related.

[image: Screenshot of Installation Options dialog]

Thank you

Comment: Choose Tool under .NET development.

Comment: You should enter your comment as an Answer and then mark it as such.  This will make it easier for others to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose **Tools** under **.NET Development**.

Comment: Please note that this only installs the setup package that you will then need to run...